# Properly embedded surfaces in handlebodies are compressible or boundary compressible?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

I've read in a couple of different places (a paper and a blog) the following fact:
if $F$ is a surface, properly embedded in a three-dimensional handlebody of genus at least two, then $F$ is either compressible or boundary compressible.

Neither of these sources included a reference or a proof and I am a bit of a three-manifold newbie.  Could somebody please direct me to reference for this fact? Or provide a proof?

Comment: I have looked somewhat carefully and (to my surprise) this result seems not to be contained in Hempel's book *3-manifolds*.  It is in Jaco's book *Lectures on three-manifold topology* but it is given as Example III.13(b) on page 37, without proof.

Comment: It is also almost (but not exactly!) contained in Waldhausen's paper *On irreducible 3-manifolds which are sufficiently large*.  It certainly follows from that work (as a collection of meridional disks in a handlebody give it a Haken hierarchy). But I don't see the exact statement.

Comment: You can find this fact as Proposition 9.3.15 here:
http://people.dm.unipi.it/martelli/Geometric_topology.pdf

Comment: Oops! Sorry Bruno, I missed that.  My only excuse is my extreme age - I didn’t grow up with your lovely book.

Comment: Neither did I :-D Thanks for your nice words

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that the surface $F$ is properly embedded in the handlebody $V$.  We induct on the genus of $V$.

In the base case $V$ has genus zero and so is a three-ball. In this case the desired result follows from a theorem of Alexander.  (Briefly, suppose that $F$ is not a sphere or a disk. Sweepout the ball $V$ by planes $(P_t)$ and track the pattern of intersections with the surface $F$.  Then there is at least one time $t'$ where $F \cap P_{t'}$ contains a compressing curve or a boundary compressing arc.)

Suppose that $V$ has genus greater than zero.  Suppose that $(D, \partial D) \subset (V, \partial V)$ is a non-separating compressing disk for $V$.  Properly isotope $F$ to minimise the intersection between $F$ and $D$.  If $F$ is disjoint from $D$ we are done by induction.  Suppose instead that $F \cap D$ contains a component $\alpha$ which is either an innermost curve or an outermost arc.  If $\alpha$ is not a (boundary-)compression for $F$ in $V$ then there is an isotopy that further reduces $|F \cap D|$, a contradiction.